# How to convert array to arguments for a function in C?

Tags: c

```c
void test(int a,int b,int c)
{
   printf("%d;%d;%d\n",a,b,c);
}

void run(void(*function)(int,int,int),int[] args,int sizeArgs)
{
    function(#passing args);
}

run(test,(int[]){4,6,9});
```

I need a function like `run` that accepts another function and an array of arguments. It is necessary that the `run` function enumerates arguments and then calls the passed function.

Comment: Python is ideally suited for the program you are writing, why would you like to port this to C?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *variadic function*. Wikipedia has an [example of how one writes such in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C).

Comment: I'm writing code in C, just pointed out an example from python

Comment: This is a question about C, not about Python. Just the mention of Python does not make the [tag:python] tag applicable.

Comment: You have to write them out. `test(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2])`

Comment: What *exactly* do you want about this? What do you want to happen if ``arguments`` is not of the right size or type? Is there any reason why you don't just pass in the array directly?

Comment: there is a function that accepts a function and an array of arguments, it is necessary that this function calls this function and enumerates arguments

Comment: @halwarsing Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose. I suggest to show the C code you already have. Use comments where you don't know how to implement a specific part.

Comment: @halwarsing please show some (even incomplete) C code, the question is very unclear.

Comment: I did an edit to try to clarify the problem. Voting to re-open now since it can be answered.

Comment: You have to implement it as already stated in [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650130/how-to-convert-array-to-arguments-for-a-function-in-c#comment124893797_70650130): `function(args[0], args[1], args[2]);` Note that this requires that `args` has at least 3 elements, and it will always use exactly 3 elements. You will get undefined behavior if you pass an array with less than 3 elements. Function `run` cannot find out the number of array elements unless you can use a specific value to indicate the last element.

Comment: I changed the code and added the size of the arguments

Comment: This is easy in C++ if you can switch languages, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

You could tweak the function to the following:

```
typedef void func3_t (int, int, int);
...
void run (func3_t* func, int size, const int args[size])
```

The function pointer syntax in C is hard to read, so therefore use `typedef`. The `typedef` here declares a function type and then we let the function take a function pointer to such a function.

I changed the `args` to `const` since they shouldn't be modified, this is called *const correctness* and is overall good practice. By placing the size parameter before the array, we can let the array refer to that variable. (This gives a pointer to a variable-length array, VLA.)

The function body would be trivial, just do some error check and otherwise leave it to the caller to provide the correct array size:

```
if(size==3)
{
  func(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void func3_t (int, int, int);

void test(int a, int b, int c)
{
  printf("%d;%d;%d\n",a,b,c);
}

void run (func3_t* func, int size, const int args[size])
{
  if(size==3)
  {
    func(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
  }
}


int main (void)
{
  run(test, 3, (int[]){4,6,9});
}
```

If code such as this is meaningful, well that's another story...

---

To create a completely variadic function which is also type safe... well, I would consider changing the program design first of all, because it likely does not make any sense. You *could* replace the function with a very evil macro such as this:

```
// BAD IDEA
#define run(func, ...) _Generic(&(__VA_ARGS__),                                      \
                         int(*)[3]: _Generic((func), void(*)(int,int,int): (func)) ) \
                       (__VA_ARGS__[0], __VA_ARGS__[1], __VA_ARGS__[2]) 

int main (void)
{
  run(test, (int[]){4,6,9});
}
```

This is actually type safe and can be expanded to support other function types... but if you are a C beginner then forget all about this macro, since it is using some rather advanced language features.

Comment: It is necessary that it does not depend on the size of the arguments

Comment: @halwarsing I was writing an answer for that, but then you changed the question to include size...

Comment: @halwarsing I added a completely variadic but admittedly crazy-looking macro solution which doesn't require size. Don't try this at home.

Answer (score -1):

The array can be passed as an agrument to a function by just passing the name of array.
int a[];---> array
fun(a);--->function calling
so we are actually passing the base address of the array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).